# dlib-19.1: Initialize dlib::matrix from image (e.g. dlib::cv_image) for DNN training

Tags: c++, opencv, deep-learning, dlib

I am currently trying to train a DNN with images I have on file (OCR context... input images per class are aggregate images of several thousand fixed size tiny images).

I have some code to open and properly segment the aggregate images into small OpenCV cv::Mat's. My problem is, there does not seem to be a way to

- train the DNN on dlib::cv_image directly (which can be wrapped around cv::Mat; I'm getting 500+ lines of compiler errors) or
- easily convert/wrap cv::Mat to dlib::matrix without copying every element

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something here, any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Note: The only variant I got to compile was calling dlib::dnn_trainer::train() with a vector of dlib::matrix (size fixed at compile time) and a vector with unsigned long labels (unsigned labels did not compile), although train() is templated on both types. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to fix the size of dlib::matrix at compile time.  Just call set_size() on it.  See also http://dlib.net/faq.html#HowdoIsetthesizeofamatrixatruntime.

Also, if you want to use something other than a dlib::matrix as input you can do that.  You just have to define your own input layer.  The interface you must implement is fully documented here: http://dlib.net/dlib/dnn/input_abstract.h.html#EXAMPLE_INPUT_LAYER.  You could also look at the existing input layers for examples.  But be sure to read the documentation as it will answer questions you are likely to have.

Comment: Thanks, I wrongly assumed everything based on generic_image would magically work with the input layer. Will use matrix for now.
Another question (but don't want to pollute SO with too many detail questions): I'm trying to verify training results I obtained using caffe with dlib. I managed to get the network to start training, but fail to get comparable results. Trying to recreate my training regime as faithfully as possible, but can't find a mention of how to set weight decay and momentum in dlib. Is this currently possible, or are they auto-set?

Comment: You can set those values to whatever you want.  All these things are discussed in the two introduction example programs.  Beyond that, the entire API is documented. On this page is a deep learning section with links to everything: http://dlib.net/ml.html.  Also, http://dlib.net/faq.html#Whereisthedocumentationforobjectfunction

Comment: Found it: it is a property of the trainer that can explicitly be set on construction: dlib::dnn_trainer<net_type> trainer(net, dlib::sgd(float weight_decay, float momentum));

Answer (score 1):

Dlib has an amazing function for this task: http://dlib.net/imaging.html#assign_image, but it makes copying of each element

here is sample code on how it can be used:

```
// mat should be greyscale image (8UC1)
void cv_to_dlib_float_matrix(const cv::Mat& mat, dlib::matrix<float>& res)
{
    cv::Mat tmp(mat.cols, mat.rows, CV_32FC1); 
    cv::normalize(mat, tmp, 0.0, 1.0, cv::NORM_MINMAX, CV_32FC1);
    dlib::assign_image(res, dlib::cv_image<float>(tmp));
}
```